# Extracting the last character from a non-empty string (DrRacket). Hope for assistance

Tags: string, scheme, racket

I'm fairly new to Scheme and I'm using DrRacket and I hope to get some much needed assistance.

I was first tasked to extract the first character from a non-empty string, which I was successful in doing so.

```
;;Signature: string-first: string -> string
;;Purpose: To extract the first character from a non-empty string
;;Tests
  (check-expect (string-first "cookies") "c")
  (check-expect (string-first "party") "p")
;;Definition: string-first
  (define (string-first str)
    (string-ith str 0))
```

Now, I am tasked with extracting the last character from a non-empty string. I cannot figure this out. My guess is that it involves "string-length" in combination with "string-ith."

Hopefully someone can help me out. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're on the right track, assuming that the string is non-empty the implementation is as simple as this:

```
(define (string-last str)
  (string-ref str (sub1 (string-length str))))
```

Explanation:

- I'm using the built-in [`string-ref`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/strings.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._string-ref%29%29) procedure, which I'm guessing does the same as your implementation of `string-ith` (always try to use existing procedures)
- A string's valid indexes start at zero and end at the string's length minus one (use [`sub1`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/generic-numbers.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._sub1%29%29) for subtracting a single unit)
- So finding the last character is a simple matter of combining [`string-ref`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/strings.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._string-ref%29%29) and [`string-length`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/strings.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._string-length%29%29), remembering that the last character will be at the index `length-1`